# awk: add a line if missing

Tags: scripting, awk

I've an awk script which processes .ICS calendar files.
I need to add the ATTENDEE line if it's missing.

I already have a script which parses all the events taking in considerations only the ones I need given a CHECKPARM criteria. I need to add the ATTENDEE if it's not present already.

```
/BEGIN:VEVENT/ { cache = 1; }

/CHECKPARM/ {
    if( index( $0, var ) )
        printf( "%s", cached_lines );
    else
        drop = 1;
    cached_lines = "";
    cache = 0;
}

# this doesn't work
#!~ /ATTENDEE/ {
#    printf ("ATTENDEE: %s", organizer);
#}

cache  {
    cached_lines = cached_lines $0 "\n";
    next;
};

!drop { print; }

/END:VEVENT/ { drop = 0; }
```

Comment: Questions that are strictly about programming would be better placed at StackOverflow. I'll try moving this one there.

Comment: Remove the tilde for correct negated match syntax. You may need to use a flag as in Fredrik Pihl's answer in order to control when the information gets printed. Otherwise the negated match will be true for every line which doesn't contain the string and the information may get printed multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a flag, if line is present, set it, if not, add line.
Something like this:

```
/ATTENDEE/ {att = 1}

!att {
    printf ("ATTENDEE: %s\n", organizer)
}
```